# Importing a class from node_module and using it in Angular 6 throws error

Tags: angular

Here's my scenario

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Nut } from 'nuts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(){
    console.log(new Nut());
  }
}
```

### node_modules/nuts (installed locally)

To be able to install this locally i had to add in `"preserveSymlinks": true` to the build options in angular.json.

#### node_modules/nuts/index.ts

```
export class Nut {
    public size: number;
}
```

### This is the error on `ng serve`

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/nuts/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/charliewalter/Desktop/my-project/peanuts/node_modules/nuts/index.tsis missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format (https://goo .gl/jB3GVv).
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/charliewalter/Desktop/my-project/peanuts/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:709:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/Users/charliewalter/Desktop/my-project/peanuts/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to compile npm packages for Angular since Angular won't support building from outside the `src/` directory.

See:
https://github.com/cjonasw/nuts/tree/master